# Lower-bounding the eigenvalues of a certain positive-semidefinite kernel matrix, as a function of the norm of the input matrix

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, sp.spectral-theory, integral-kernel

Let $\phi:[-1,1] \to \mathbb R$ be a function such that

- $\phi$ is $\mathcal C^\infty$ on $(-1,1)$.
- $\phi$ is continuous at $\pm 1$.

For concreteness, and if it helps, In my specific problem I have $\phi(t) := t \cdot (\pi - \arccos(t)) + \sqrt{1-t^2}$.

Now, given a $k \times d$ matrix $U$ with linearly independent rows, consider the $k \times k$ positive-semidefinite matrix $C_U=(c_{i,j})$ defined by $c_{i,j} := K_{\phi}(u_i,u_j)$, where

$$
K_\phi(x,y) := \|x\|\|y\|\phi(\frac{x^\top y}{\|x\|\|x\|})
$$

> **Question.** How express the eigenvalues of $C$ in terms of $U$ and $\phi$ ?

I'm ultimated interested in **lower-bounding** $\lambda_{\min}(C_U)$ in terms of some norm of $U$ (e.g spectral norm or Frobenius norm).

---

Let $X$ be the $(d-1)$-dimensional unit-sphere in $\mathbb R^d$, equipped with its uniform measure $\sigma_{d-1}$, and consider the integral operator $T_\phi: L^{2}(X) \to L^2(X)$ defined by
$$
T_{\phi}(f):x \mapsto \int K_{\phi}(x,y)f(y)d\sigma_{d-1}(y).
$$
It is easy to see that $T_\phi$ is a compact positive-definite operator.

> **Question.** Are the eigenvalues of $C_U$ be expressed as a function of (eigenvalues of) $K_{\phi}$ ?